# imx6q sabre board microphone

Tags: analog, microphone

I have been trying to record audio using the circuit below. It is different from the normal microphone circuit in that the MIC_IN and MICBIAS are separate paths. I tried to connect an electret microphone to the audio jack and short the MIC_RAW and MICBIAS2_RAW path but no sound was recorded. I used ALSA arecord to record. Does anyone know if I am connecting it correctly?

[image]

Comment: I gather that's probably the input circuit on the development board? It might be worth adding a bit more context on the software side, my guess is that MICBIAS is probably an output and possibly the drivers need MICROPHONE_DET to be high so also mention if you used a plug or tried connecting it directly.

Comment: Yes, it is the input circuit on the development board. For the software side, i am using arecord and the settings in alsamixer is setup according to the manual to enable the analog microphone.

Comment: I am wondering if the circuit is ok as most other circuits have their MICBIAS and MIC_IN tied together..

Comment: Use a voltmeter and see , do you really have a bias there?